# Formatting a string in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a string FI234567. And I want to format it like 23456-7.

I have to do this using XSL 1.0.
I am trying to do this with functions substring, translate & received the output as 234567.
Now I need my output as 23456-7
Any suggestions!

Comment: One example does not make a rule. Please explain the exact logic behind the transformation.

Comment: Thanks Michael.Although it wasn't required to understand the whole logic behind the whole transformation,but to have an idea behind formatting a string.I performed it like this and it worked. <xsl:variable name="FormatCode_First">
<xsl:value-of select="substring(InputString,1,string-length(InputString)-1)"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="FormatCode_Second">
<xsl:value-of select="substring(InputString,string-length(InputString))"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($FormatCode_First)"/>
<xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($FormatCode_Second)"/>

Answer (score 1):

I performed it like this and it worked.

```
<xsl:variable name="FormatCode_First">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(InputString,1,string-length(InputString)-1)"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="FormatCode_Second">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(InputString,string-length(InputString))"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($FormatCode_First)"/>
<xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($FormatCode_Second)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this for text like FF1234:

```
<xsl:template match="text1">
    <xsl:variable name="var1" select="replace(., '([A-z]+)([0-9]+)', '$2', 'i')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="var2" select="substring($var1, 1, string-length($var1)-1)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="var3" select="substring($var1, string-length($var1))"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($var2, '-', $var3)"/>
</xsl:template>
```